# CPU high usage of the usleep on Cent OS 6.3

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, kernel

I compile the code below on cent os 5.3 and cent os 6.3:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <list>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
pthread_mutex_t _mutex;
pthread_spinlock_t spinlock;

list<int *> _task_list;

void * run(void*);
int main()
{
    int worker_num  = 3;
        pthread_t pids[worker_num];
        pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, NULL);
        for (int worker_i = 0; worker_i < worker_num; ++worker_i)
        {
                pthread_create(&(pids[worker_i]), NULL, run, NULL);
        }
    sleep(14);
}


void *run(void * args)
{
        int *recved_info;
    long long start;
        while (true)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
                if (_task_list.empty())
                {
                        recved_info = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        recved_info = _task_list.front();
                        _task_list.pop_front();
                }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);

                if (recved_info == 0)
                {
                        int f = usleep(1);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

While running on the 5.3, you can't even find the process on top, cpu usage is around 0%. But on cent os 6.3, it's about 20% with 6 threads on a 4 cores cpu.

So I check the a.out with *time* and *stace* , the results are about that:

On 5.3:

```
real    0m14.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

On 6.3:

```
real    0m14.002s
user    0m1.484s
sys  0m1.160s
```

the strace:

on 5.3:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.71    0.002997           0     14965           nanosleep
  8.29    0.000271         271         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        10         4 open
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         4         4 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        38         4 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.003268                 15092        13 total
```

on 6.3:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.99    1.372813          36     38219           nanosleep
  0.01    0.000104           0       409        43 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           open
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        15           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         7         7 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    1.372917                 38716        50 total
```

The time and the strace results are not the same test, so data is a little different. But I think it can show something.

I check the kernel config CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS, CONFIG_HPET and CONFIG_HZ:

On 5.3:

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HPET
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
CONFIG_HPET=y
# CONFIG_HPET_RTC_IRQ is not set
# CONFIG_HPET_MMAP is not set
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HZ
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
```

On 6.3:

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HPET
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
CONFIG_HPET=y
CONFIG_HPET_MMAP=y
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_HZ
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
```

In fact, I also try the code on arch on ARM and xubuntu13.04-amd64-desktop, the same as the cent os 6.3.

So what can I do to figure out the reason of the different CPU usages?

Does it have anything with the kernel config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, it has to do with the kernel config. `usleep(1)` will try to sleep for one microsecond.  Before high resolution timers, it was not possible to sleep for less than a jiffy (in your case HZ=1000 so 1 jiffy == 1 millisecond).

On CentOS 5.3 which does not have these high resolution timers, you would sleep between 1ms and 2ms[1].  On CentOS 6.3 which has these timers, you're sleeping for close to one microsecond.  That's why you're using more cpu on this platform: you're simply polling your task list 500-1000 times more.

If you change the code to `usleep(1000)`, CentOS 5.3 will behave the same.  CentOS 6.3 cpu time will decrease and be in the same ballpark as the program running on CentOS 5.3

There is a full discussion of this in the Linux manual: run `man 7 time`.

Note that your code should use condition variables instead of polling your task list at a certain time interval.  That's a more efficient and clean way to do what you're doing.

Also, your main should really join the threads instead of just sleeping for 14 seconds.

[1] There is one exception.  If your application was running under a realtime scheduling policy (SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR), it would busy-wait instead of sleeping to sleep close to the right amount.  But by default you need root privileges

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try the condition variables.