# High CPU Load by JAVA and CentOS 6.3

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cpu, centos6

I am seeing high cpu utilization while running java program. I found jstack can help to debug the things where it is stuck and eating the CPU. I got the output with jstack and found there are few threads are in BLOCKED state.

Here I have used java 1.7 and to confirm the load issue I have replaced the java with older 1.6 on the same OS ie CentOS 6.3 but the issue still remain, since have tested with combination of  java 1.6 (1.7 as well)  and centos 5.4 which works great and using less cpu.

There is nothing has been changed except the OS which is centos 6.3 only getting load issue.

How can I find the relevant code which pointed threads as BLOCKED into jstack output, following are the output from my findings

```
OS - CentOS 6.3 x86_64 (2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64)
CPU core - 8
Ram - 16GB
Java version - "1.7.0_17"
```

jstack output:

```
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

none
null_check
null_assert
range_check
class_check
array_check
intrinsic
bimorphic
unloaded
uninitialized
unreached
unhandled
constraint
div0_check
age
predicate
loop_limit_check
Thread 4514: (state = BLOCKED)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 4493: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=135 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=151 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=3, line=177 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 4491: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=133 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Java Info Output:

```
Java System Properties:

java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment

java.vm.version = 23.7-b01

sun.boot.library.path = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64

hadoop.root.logger = INFO,console

java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/

java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation

path.separator = :

file.encoding.pkg = sun.io

java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

sun.os.patch.level = unknown

sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD

user.country = US

user.dir = /home/ravi

java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification

java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_17-b02

java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

os.arch = amd64

java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/endorsed

line.separator =


VM Flags:

-Xmx4000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=//opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/lib/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=//opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str= -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=//opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms256m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
```

Comment: Blocked threads don't use any CPU. They're waiting for something to do.

Comment: like david said, youre interested in the threads that are RUNNABLE. those are the ones that may be using the CPU.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Agreed, but it should be more on wait, as I said the CentOS 6.3 Kernel version '2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64' which look bug it self, do any one have updates for this. 
Ref:
http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5813
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=870573 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726872/cpu-high-usage-of-the-usleep-on-cent-os-6-3